# How to find $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{b^a}{\Gamma(a)}\frac{x^{n+a-3}e^{-bx}(n^2-2nx+x^2)}{n!e^x-x^n} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, definite-integrals

How to compute the next integral:

$$I(n) =  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{b^a}{\Gamma(a)}\frac{x^{n+a-3}e^{-bx}(n^2-2nx+x^2)}{n!e^x-x^n} dx \ ?$$

First I tried by elementary methods without much luck.
Next I tried by with Laplace aproximation but the algebra is nasty.

Anybody know how to use special functions or how to go about this problem?

Comment: You can't solve this unless you know which variable you are integrating with respect to, and there are a lot of variables, some quite arbitrary, others not so.

Comment: Oh sorry, I want integrate respect x.
I added the variable in the question.

Comment: Might be naif, but Mellin transform and residue theorem?

Comment: what da ....?!?

Comment: the first fraction is super useless

Comment: also, do you want an approximation or an exact closed form?

Comment: The ideal would be a closed form... but with a reasonable approximation  could be happy